# Dynamically constructed objects with MooseX::Traits

Tags: perl, moose

I have some code using [MooseX::Traits](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Traits) that does a fair bit of dynamic loading of roles.  Setting requires in one of the roles doesn't seem to work because of the dependency of roles on each other.  Is there a correct way to achieve the pattern shown below, this code dies with `died: Moose::Exception::RequiredMethodsNotImplementedByClass ('Constructor::Plugin' requires the method 'frobnicate' to be implemented by 'MooseX::Traits::__ANON__::SERIAL::1'`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                             
package Constructor;
use Moose;
with 'MooseX::Traits';
use namespace::autoclean;
has '+_trait_namespace' => ( default => __PACKAGE__);
sub load {
    my ($class, $plugin) = @_;
    my $obj_with_plugin = $class->new_with_traits(traits => ["$plugin"]);
    return $obj_with_plugin;
}
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;

package Constructor::Plugin;
use Moose::Role;
requires 'frobnicate';
with 'Constructor::Plugin::Component';
1;

package Constructor::Plugin::Component;
use Moose::Role;
sub frobnicate { "zark!\n" }

1;
package main;
use Test::More;
use Test::Exception;
my $thing;
lives_ok {$thing = Constructor->load('Plugin')} "instantiated ok";
ok $thing->frobnicate, "frobnicates ok";
done_testing;
```

Comment: All of those `1;` in your file do nothing.

Comment: yeah but if I want to move stuff over into a dir structure it's one less thing to forget.

Answer (score 1):

How about loading Constructor::Plugin::Component via MooseX::Traits also?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                             
package Constructor;
use Moose;
with 'MooseX::Traits';
use namespace::autoclean;
has '+_trait_namespace' => ( default => __PACKAGE__);
sub load {
    my ($class, @plugin) = @_;
    my $obj_with_plugin = $class->new_with_traits(traits => [@plugin]);
    return $obj_with_plugin;
}
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;

package Constructor::Plugin;
use Moose::Role;
requires 'frobnicate';
1;

package Constructor::Plugin::Component;
use Moose::Role;
sub frobnicate { "zark!\n" }
1;

package main;
use Test::More;
use Test::Exception;
my $thing;
lives_ok {$thing = Constructor->load('Plugin', 'Plugin::Component')} "instantiated ok";
ok $thing->frobnicate, "frobnicates ok";
done_testing;
```